# How to add jquery js files in React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have recently switched to React inorder to achieve single page application

Previously I had 8 html files and 8 js files which were linked by script tag

```
<script  src="pathHere"> </script>
```

Now as I switched to React. Now the html pages are replaced by components with extension .js

How can I link some components(which have html content) with js (which contain js in jquery format)
I tried to add component of js file in my jsx

```
import FirstJsFile from "../ApiCalls/FirstJsFile";
const Display = () =>{
    return (
        <div>
     // jsx written here
    <FistJsFile/> // This is  the js file which  conatins js in form of jquery
        </div>
    )
}

export default Display;
```

Then the js file contains this

```
const FristJsFile = () =>{
    return (
        <>{
            $(function(){
                console.log("Jquery getting loaded")
                }
        </>
    )
}

export default FirstJsFile
```

Comment: At the top-level of the React application there's still an HTML page.  You can add `<script>` tags to that page.  *However*, you *probably shouldn't* be mixing React and jQuery.  Not unless you really know what you're doing.  If you're just throwing together plugins for functionality, it's probably going to fail in a variety of ways as both jQuery and React do very different things with the DOM.

Comment: Double down on what @David says.... JQuery and React have pretty orthogonal approaches to UI management that don't generally mix well at all. IMHO you should ditch jquery if using React.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [react-state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state) instead of jquery.